# How to insert column of cells from one sheet to a single cell of another sheet in OpenOffice?

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc

I have a sheet 'MODELS' with columns of data, each column varies in how many cells (rows). I'm wanting to paste a column from this sheet into another sheet 'COMBINED' into a single cell. 
For my first cell in COMBINED, I tried using formula:

='MODELS'.A1:A15

However, this resulted in only displaying the data in cell (MODELS) A1 instead of the entire range (A1:A15).

Is there a formula to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Excel/OpenOffice has a built-in function to do this. You could write a user-defined function (UDF) or a Macro using VBA to accomplish this. Here's a thread which you might find useful:
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/16401-concatenate-range-cells.html